# Magento 2 - SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, mariadb, magento2

I have a problem installing Magento2 and i think it's all because of mariaDB, when i access to mysql at the terminal, i must execute it like superuser:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

and i think magento2 when tried to access to the database to install it, it can't. In the step "add a database i fill the data fields and this message appear:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

i tried to change privileges in mariaDB... and i do something bad because, when i execute:

```
$ service mysql restart

Failed to add /run/systemd/ask-password to directory watch: No space left on device
```

but i'm open to other options.

Comment: Are you out of disk space?

Comment: i have a lot of space

Answer (score 0):

Are you install mageto2 by using git repo ?
If yes, then command line should include db user name and password

```
bin/magento setup:install --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user=magento --db-password=magento
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for those who are facing this issue

```
bin/magento setup:install \
--base-url='http://127.0.0.1/mage244d1/' \
--db-host='localhost' \
--db-name='magento_244_d1' \
--db-user='nilesh' \
--db-password='<Password>' \
--admin-firstname='xcv' \
--admin-lastname='xcv' \
--admin-email='xcv@xcv.com' \
--admin-user='xcv' \
--admin-password='xcv' \
--language=en_US \
--currency=USD \
--timezone=America/Chicago \
--use-rewrites=1
```

Wrap username and password in 'quote'

Answer (score -2):

I don't understand why it happens, but I resolve it with reinstalling mysql and AVOIDING do

`sudo mysql_secure_installation`